# How to put TextView below RecyclerView in NestedScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to create a layout in which cart price and the total price will be displayed below the recycler view but when text view is placed below recycler view it gets invisible

**I have searched on the internet about this but didn't find any solution**

[image: here is an image of the layout]

when text view is below the recycler view it gets invisible

Thanks in advance

```
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
        android:layout_weight = "8.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".ShoppingCartActivity" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight = "1.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTextTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_tv"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Total Right"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>



</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Need to bring cart price and total price outside `NestedScrollView`. Suggestion Make `RelativeLayout` as root layout. Add cart price and total price with `alignParentBottom="true"` attribute and add  `NestedScrollView` above the cart and total price.

Comment: NestedScrollView can directly host only one child

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8.5"
            tools:context=".ShoppingCartActivity" />


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTextTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Total Right"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    tools:listitem="@layout/tek_satir_playlist" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTextTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="224dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="224dp"
        android:text="Total Right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not use weight and weightSum attributes for relative layout.
As I understand from your code You do not need to use the nested scroll, try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_container"
    tools:context=".ShoppingCartActivity" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTextTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Total Right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the first sub Layout in `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` to `ConstraintLayout` too easily position your `RelativeLayout` in it.

bellow is the completed code, I hope it would help...

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        tools:context=".ShoppingCartActivity" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cartRecyclerView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTextTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_tv"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Total Right"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

       <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartFragmentTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:margin_top="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Total Cost"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
 <LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```